# Upgrading pgfplots fails (TeX Live)

Tags: pgfplots, texlive, texlive-2019

(Note: closely related to this [unanswered question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53401351/8930486))

Since my documents use `pgfplots` 1.16 (using the command `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`) and I am having 1.15, I want to update `pgfplots`. However, when I try to do this, I get an error:

```
$ sudo tlmgr update pgfplots
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

This suggests that I have an old version of TeX Live. This I don't understand, because I installed TeX Live last week. Also, in my `texlive` folder, is see `2019`:

```
$ ls /usr/local/texlive/
2019  texmf-local
```

However, when I ask `tlmgr` for my version, it shows `2017`:

```
$ tlmgr version
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr revision 46207 (2018-01-04 19:34:36 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017
```

This makes me think that reinstalling TeX Live - as suggested on https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html - will not work.

Given the error above, how could I upgrade `pgfplots`?

Comment: sounds as if you have two texlive. Check your pathes.

Comment: You could uninstall Debian's and install a 'dummy' package or you could leave Debian's alone and adjust `PATH` to put the upstream one in `/usr/local/texlive` first.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. It may seem very obvious or even silly to you, but you helped me a lot! I removed the texlive under `/usr/share/texlive` (I wasn't even aware of this, which is kind of stupid because `tlmgr version` already showed this) and now it works :)